# How to Select a list by having all the lists in that list

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I haw this model:

```
public class Obj1
{
public long ID { get; set; }
public long Name { get; set; }
public List<int> NumberList { get; set; }
}
```

The values in Obj1 List:

```
List<Obj1> lst1 = new List<Obj1>();

lst1.Add(new Obj1()
{
ID = 1,
Name = "t1",
NumberList = new List<int>{1,3,4}
});
lst1.Add(new Obj1()
{
ID = 2,
Name = "t2",
NumberList = new List<int>{1,4,5}
});
lst1.Add(new Obj1()
{
ID = 3,
Name = "t3",
NumberList = new List<int>{4,5,6}
});
lst1.Add(new Obj1()
{
ID = 4,
Name = "t4",
NumberList = new List<int>{5,7,8}
});
```

I want to select list1 provided all list2 is in it. Also list 2 is equal to:

`List<int> lst2 = new List<int>(){4,5};`

I use this code, But it doesn't work properly:

`var FinalList = lst1.Where(item => item.NumberList.Any(item2 => lst2.Contains(item2)).ToList();`

The correct output should be this:

```
{
ID = 2,
Name = "t2",
NumberList = new List<int>{1,4,5}
},
{
ID = 3,
Name = "t3",
NumberList = new List<int>{4,5,6}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want all `Obj` items in `lst1` if the `NumberList` property is a superset of `lst2`. You can query this like so:

```
var finalList = lst1.Where(l => !lst2.Except(l.NumberList).Any()).ToList();
```

Full [example](https://ideone.com/6P24qD) on Ideone.